# each <p> is added in all .content divs and not only in one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs .content.

And I have a button "add" to add paragraphs to .content divs.

I want to have a maximum of 3 paragraphs in each .content div, when this two .content divs already have 3 paragraphs I want to create a new .content div and add there the new paragraph.

But its not working properly, when I add a new paragraph to .content div, the paragraph is added in all .content divs, and I just want to add a paragraph in one div to in all.

Do you see how to do this correctly?

```
$(document).on('click', '#input', function () {
    $('#input').val('');
});


$(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    alert(input);
    var divContentSize = $(".container > *").length;
    alert(divContentSize);
    var relDiv = $(".container > div").filter(function () {
        return $(this).children().length !== 3;
    });

    if (relDiv.length) {
        relDiv.prepend("<p>" + input + "</p>");
    }
    else {
        $(".container").append("<div class=content><p>" + input + "</p></div>");
    }

}); 


$(".prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".container .content:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".container .content:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($(".container .content:visible").prev().length != 0) { 
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });}
    else {
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".container .content:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `relDiv` will likely refer to multiple elements ... `relDiv.prepend` will prepend to all those elements

Comment: your "working example" doesn't do squat

Comment: Try `$(".container").append('<div class="content"><p>' + input + '</p></div>');` (in demo) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem continues. Every paragraph that is added is added in all .content divs and not just in one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this fiddle to see if it accomplishes all that you want. I stripped down your fiddle just to show the functionality and also make browsing the code for the specific problem easier.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r13uqhg3/5/)

I basically used jquery to traverse the elements and decide what goes where on your click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(){
    //get last child of class content of container
    var children = $(".container").children(".content");

    //add new content if none exist
    if(children.length <= 0 || $(children[children.length-1]).children("p").length == 3){
        var div = $("<div class='content'/>");

        $(".container").append(div);
    }

    //refresh children
    children = $(".container").children(".content");

    $(children[children.length - 1]).append("<p>Newly added</p>");

});
});
```

**UPDATE:** Just updated the fiddle so its easier to see the separation of the divs and p tags that are being added to the DOM

New Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r13uqhg3/6/)

UPDATE: Updated the fiddle to run with the two div content as stated in comment.
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r13uqhg3/7/)

Matches code below:

```
    function addP2div(div){
    $(div).append("<p>Newly added</p>");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        //get children of class content of container
        var children = $(".container").children(".content");

        //set variable to see if added
        var added = false;

        //add new content if none exist
        if(children.length > 1){
            //check each child to see if it can accept a third p        
            for(i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                var elem = children[i];
                //skip if 3 p exist
                if($(elem).children("p").length == 3){
                    continue;
                }

                //add p here
                addP2div(elem);

                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //create new div and add to it
        if(!added){
            var div = $("<div class='content'/>");

            $(".container").append(div);


            addP2div($(".container").children('.content').last());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your solution just add paragraphs in one div. What Im trying to do is to add one paragraph in only one div, and when the two .content divs already have 3 paragraphs each one I want to create one more .content div to add there the new paragraph.

Comment: Is it that the divs will have two paragraphs by default? And no it does not add to one div, if you inspect the DOM you would see a new div being created once 3 paragraphs have been added to one div